# How to line-break buttons using Unity 3D New UI

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I'm not familiar with Unity's new UI system of 4.6 and later. I would like to display a series of buttons on screen and have them center-aligned and breaks into the next line when screen width is reached. The old OnGUI function no longer seem working so I wonder how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [UI's layout system](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/comp-UIAutoLayout.html). Usually, you just create a [Layout Group](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-HorizontalLayoutGroup.html) and populate it with objects that have [Layout Element](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-LayoutElement.html) component.

Comment: I added the grid layout group but when the line startes all elements are left aligned. Can I make them centered?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `Child alignment` property of the `Layout Group` component?

Comment: The child alignment positions all buttons as a whole, how can I make each line horizontally centered?

Comment: Solution found! A community plugin called FlowLayoutGropus works perfectly, though Unity should officially include theses functions. Here's download link: https://bitbucket.org/ddreaper/unity-ui-extensions thanks for pointing me out Layout Group